# Orange spots at hot dip galvanized surface

Tags: structural-engineering, chemical-engineering, corrosion

I like to ask you about orange spots after galvanizing of Steel Purlins. I attached some of the pictures. Please advice the solution with your expertise.
Thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3peT.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsF82.jpg)

[image]

Comment: They were not clean to start with.

Comment: The zinc looks thin for hot dipped.

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't orange spots, they're rust.  You didn't get a good zinc application, either from how it was resting in the container or from insufficient surface prep.

Note that galvanized steel will rust where the coating has been rubbed or scratched off.